# Change ZFS mountpoint property without remounting

Tags: migration, zfs, mount

I want to replace one ZFS filesystem (volume in a pool) with another ZFS filesystem (another volume in the same pool).  Rebooting is okay, but I'd like to avoid single user mode.

When I try to set `mountpoint=none` on the old filesystem, ZFS tries to unmount it, which fails due to files being in use.  Consequently, I can't set `mountpoint=/data` on the new filesystem due to something being mounted there.  The `mountpoint` properties are also not written to the filesystems.

If I reboot, the old filesystem is still mounted, services will start using files on there and I can't unmount it anymore.  Is there a way to write the `mountpoint` properties on the filesystems without actually changing anything that's mounted, and then reboot so that the new filesystem is in use when the system comes up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer versions of OpenZFS, there is the `zfs set -u` flag.

```
zfs set -u mountpoint=/data-old zpool/data1
zfs set -u mountpoint=/data zpool/data2
```

Now the properties are changed, but nothing is changed to the current mountpoints; `/data` still points to `zpool/data1`, but after a reboot, it will be `zpool/data2`.

Comment: For those wondering what counts as "newer versions of OpenZFS": you need to be using version 2.2.0 or higher.  
Version [2.2.0](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/releases/tag/zfs-2.2.0) was released on October 13th, 2023; and the `-u` flag was added in commit [4e16964](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/commit/4e16964e1c1555704f6e7cd031ae32e1491f0b11) on October 2nd, 2023.